# bootstrap datepicker not loading properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datepicker

Need your help in this weird behavior in bootstarp date picker. It happens intermittently. The date picker is now showing at the correct position (i.e. next to the datepicker icon) and also not showing the months, instead it is showing dates, i.e. the default properties. So what I understood is, it is not executing the attributes (i.e. container, format, minViewMode, etc).

Note: I don't have any working code for this to create fiddle. 
[image: Expected position]
[image: Sometimes the position come here]
I have the below code:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mywebsite.css" type="text/css"/>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".datepickerIcon", function () {    
        $('#myDatepicker').bootstrapDP({
              container: '#mydatepicker-custom-position',
                format: "yyyy-mm",
                startView: "year", 
                minViewMode: "months",
                startDate: startDate,
                endDate: endDate,
                autoclose: false,
                multidate: true,
                forceParse: false
            }).bootstrapDP( "show");
      });
});
```

Comment: Is your jquery datepicker call code inside of a `$(document).ready()` function? (I don't know if the code you show is just an extract). If not, do it and try again. It could posibly be that the datepicker call is being made before the input are fully rendered to the DOM.

Comment: @A.Iglesias: Thanks for your reply. Yes, it is inside ready function and on click of an icon. Update the code.

Comment: Don't create the datetimepicker inside a click function, create it outside of that. The datetimepicker will automatically add a click handler to the element.